# Customize the woocommerce unique product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, elementor

I have a problem that I can't solve, and I hope someone can help me. The company's online store is built with WordPress, WooCommerce, and Elementor.

I confess that I don't have much expertise in the WordPress environment!

Recently, for some reason I couldn't identify, the 'Add to Cart' button disappeared from the product page. I've tried various approaches to restore it, but without success. My last attempt was to edit the WooCommerce plugin. In a version used on my localhost, I added the code below to the file `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/single-product/single-product.php`, and it worked, but in the production version, it doesn't work. The difference between the two versions is that the localhost version doesn't use Elementor.

```
global $product;

echo apply_filters(
    'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url($product->add_to_cart_url()),
        esc_attr($product->get_id()),
        esc_attr($product->get_sku()),
        $product->is_purchasable() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
        esc_attr($product->get_type()),
        esc_html($product->add_to_cart_text())
    ),
    $product
);
```

What I'm trying to do is make WooCommerce recognize the single-product.php and disregard the page created in Elementor, which was previously used. Does anyone have an idea on how to force this behavior?

I'm using Woocommerce version 8.5.1, Wordpress 6.4.2 and PHP 7.4

I tried to directly modify the single-product.php file in the WooCommerce plugin, adding the purchase button next to the product image, but it had no effect whatsoever. It's as if I hadn't made any PHP modifications. Does anyone know why the single-product.php file is not being loaded?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a page where the add to cart button is missing?

Comment: @ChadPhillips Yes, I can! https://www.ipmarket.com.br/produto/camera-ip-axis-p5654-e-camera-ptz-21x-de-zoom-e-hdtv/

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to see that the button was not added to the page, but hidden.  You should undo your edits to the plugin files.   Woocommerce templates are being overridden here.  This is one way to do that:  https://woo.com/document/template-structure/  I also see there is a plugin:  https://elementor.com/features/woocommerce-builder/  This plugin specifically is for controlling your product page templates with Elementor, so I would look to see if it's installed and just deactivate it.  There could be another plugin. You'll have to hunt around.